# How to abstract types of transformations

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an program that already transform POJOs to xml via JAXB and this is done by adding a the elements to a list in this form

```
List<JAXBElement<?>> elementsToTransform = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<?>>();
```

In other method I just transform and populate the **elementsToTransform** as xml, the firm of this method is something like this

```
private List<JAXBElement<?>> transform(Student student)
```

Now I need to add a way to transform to Json via Gson and I want to abstract both declaration and method in order to support both formats but the implementation is pretty hardcoded to xml and I need to fit this solution as the way it is build with xml because this depends on other functionality that I do not want to modify so I would know if there is a way I can support both formats and which will be the better choice for this problem

At the end I would like to have something like this in the elementsToTransform list

```
JAXBElement(0)
JAXBElement(1)
JAXBElement(2)
String(3)(this will be Json)
```

Comment: so **elementsToTransform** can contain both _JAXBElement<?>_ and _String_ at the same time ? or for XML it should be like _List<JAXBElement<?>>_ and for Json _List<String>_ ?

Comment: I would like that elemenToTransform can contain at the same time either jaxbelements and string for json but the method currently return list of jaxbelements because it is the main mechanism for Transform messages(Students,Grades that is the reason that I have JAXBElements<? >) , that part its abstracted and the implementation for each transformer is separated from each other and at the end an iteration for elementsToTransform will happend and each elements will be post it into a queue, I need the same list contain both formats

Comment: _that part is abstracted_ , you mean Student and Grade has _common Interface or Super Class_ ? or do you have separate methods like **private List<JAXBElement<?>> transform(Student student)** , **private List<JAXBElement<?>> transform(Grade grade)**

Comment: I mean Student and Grade are not related but both uses this functionality in order to Transform to xml but both have its implementations separated

Comment: you may use **List<?> elementsToTransform** and while iteration you may check *instanceof* _JAXBElement<?>_ or _String_ , and cast it to _JAXBElement<?>_ or _String_ afterwards

Comment: Can you have a wrapped method instead?

Answer (score 0):

> Implement a wrapped class to incorporate both a String or JAXBElement. This can be identified by the enum Type. The convertion for each type can be implemented as an interface method.

```
interface IConvert{
 JSONObject convert(WrappedObject o){
}
```

The Type Enum can be defined as follows

```
enum Type implements IConvert{
 STRING {
  public JSONObject convert(WrappedObject o){
    String str = o.getString();
    //use Gson here and convert;
    return json;
  } 
 },
  JAXB {
  public JSONObject convert(WrappedObject o){
    JAXBElement jax = o.getJAX();
    //use Gson here and convert;
    return json;
  } 
 };
}
```

Finally the WrappedObject will look like this :

```
class WrappedObject {
 private String str;
 private JAXBElement jax;
 private Type type;

 public WrappedObject(String str){
  this.str=str
  this.type=Type.STRING;
 }

 public WrappedObject(JAXBElement jax){
  this.jax=jax
  this.type=TYPE.JAXB;
 } 

 public TYPE getType(){
  return this.type;
 }

 public JSONObject convert(){
  return type.convert(this);
 } 

 //..other getters and setters
}
```

Hope this answers your design pattern question.

Comment: `interface IConvert{
 JSONObject convert(WrappedObject o){
}`
Should return a generic  or Type(the enum)?

Comment: Based on what @jam wanted, the transformation returns a JSONObject from the elementsToTransform list. I believe you can modify the code a little to return Generics here as well. But it would make sense that it also is an abstract class or interface.